# Unity: Gravity in all directions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics, game-development

I am trying to make a game with magnets. Each magnet has its own magnetic field which pulls the player towards the magnet.

The player should then be able to walk alongside the magnet on its entire side.

The player should not be pulled towards the center.

Right now I have done this by adding velocity to the player towards the magnet, this works fine.

[image: Magnetic field towards the whole area, not the center]

The issue right now is that the player should rotate with his feet towards the magnet. Right now I can't figure out how to change the rotation of the player based on the rotation of the magnet. Which results in the player being on its side or upside down on the magnet in some case.

I am also using a third-person camera from unity standard assets, sometimes when the player is rotated the camera can only look up and down. To fix this I use a rotate function around World.Space.

[image: Player on the magnet]

Comment: You will need to use raycast towards the face of floor and take the normal of the hit to rotate your character.

Comment: The answer to this question depends heavily on how you want the game to work and feel in detail. Should the camera rotate with the player, which would be most simply solved by having the world rotate, not the player. If you have to rotate the player, you'll need to have a basic understanding of 3D geometry like normals, spaces and of lerping.

Comment: @GabrielPereira Thank you for your response. I have been trying to implement your solution. So far I managed to cast a raycast to the magnet and take the normal. How can I use the normal to rotate the player the correct way?

For example when the roatation of the cube is (0, 0, 0) and the player has a rotation of (0,0,0) aswell I get a normal of (0, 0, -1). The correct rotation of the player should then be (-90, 0, 0) or (90, 0, 0), I just don't see how I can use the normal to get the rotation

Comment: @FriseFreek can you try this:
transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, rayCastHit.normal);

Answer (score 0):

You should get the position relative, the magnet as parent and your player as child. To do that you could create a different gameObject with the same position as the player, and set it as child to the magnet (or have a child on the magnet which you change its position (absolute position)).

Once you've done that, you normalize the localposition of the magnetChild and you make the player lookAt (there's a function in Unity) this vector + player.position. And you'll have to rotate the player 90º from the x-axis (to make that not the front of the player is looking to it, but the head).

I haven't tried it, but give it a try maybe it works. Something like:

```
magnetChild.position = player.position;
player.LookAt(player.position + magnetChild.localPosition.normalized);
player.Rotate(90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```